# We can't find who or what you're looking for seems like person is not available

Tags: sharepoint-online

> We can't find who or what you're looking for
>
> Seems like the person you're looking for is not available.
>
> Are you looking at your own profile? It might take some time before your account is completely set up. Please come back in a little while.

the user is already added but unable to access, how to fix it?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is an external user. It is possible that you have a similar user (name, username) and there is a mismatch in SP profiles?

Try deleting the user using SharePoint Online Management Shell and re-adding him:

```
Connect-SPOService
Get-SPOExternalUser
Remove-SPOExternalUser
```

If that doesn't help, you can always contact Microsoft Support, opening a service request from the Admin Portal. They will help you and I think they can even remove the user for you (not 100% sure though).